# How to detect PermGen free memory

Tags: java, grails, groovy

What is the best way to work out the current PermGen usage in a Grails app?

I'm trying to do some graphing of

> Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

And I'd like to also measure the free PermGen space. Most of the search engine + Stack Overflow results on this matter are on handling the PermGenOutOfMemory-like errors, I'd just like to access the stats on these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connect to it using [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/index.html).  Theres no way for you to programmatically determine the PermGen size in your application.  You can use the [MemoryMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) to do simple memory reporting, but stick to using the tools I mentioned to get a more detailed picture.

Comment: Maybe a [link to a howto](http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.com/2011/04/finding-current-permgen-size-via.html)?

Comment: See, I'd prefer if there was a way within the application I could determine it, that way I can simply and automatically push that to a DB for reporting. But thank you, MemoryMXBean looks like a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final RuntimeMXBean memMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        final String prefix = "-XX:MaxPermSize=";
        final List<String> jvmArgs = memMXBean.getInputArguments();
        String maxPermSize = null;
        for (final String jvmArg : jvmArgs) {
            if (jvmArg.startsWith(prefix)) {
                maxPermSize = jvmArg.substring(prefix.length());
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("MaxPermSize is " + maxPermSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [**ManagementFactory**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html) could be the source, one of the pools returned from List **getMemoryPoolMXBeans()** should be PermGen.

Comment: I could be wrong here - but I don't think PermGen is reported.